# How can I get the Quill editor authorship module to turn highlighting on and off?

Tags: quill

I am using the Quill Editor http://quilljs.com/

And it has an authorship module which highlights the edits according to which user made them. But what if you want to turn the highlights off, and then back on? How can I control the authorship module to turn highlights on and off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't documented well but there's an `enable` and `disable` function call you can use.

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor');
var authorship = quill.addModule('authorship');
authorship.disable();
```

If it's convenient, `enable(false)` is the same as `disable()`.